# Double Join Query Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three models, JobPosting, Job, and Organization. The relations are below:

1. An Organization has many Jobs.
2. A Job belongs to an Organization and has many JobPostings.
3. A JobPosting belongs to a Job.

A Job has an attribute called `job_type`, and I am able to find all of the JobPostings that are related to a Job with a specific `job_type` using the query:

```
JobPosting.joins(:job).where(jobs: { :job_type => 'volunteer' })
```

But what I am struggling with is doing the same kind of thing but with an Organization attribute. A Organization has a attribute called `department`, how can I query for the JobPosting's that relate to an organization through a Job that has a specific department. The reason I am having trouble is because Organizations are essentially two levels up, whereas Job's are only one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can join the two relations as follows:

```
JobPosting.
  joins(job: :organization).
  where(jobs: { job_type: 'volunteer' }, organizations: { organizations_attr1: 'value_to_test' })
```

`joins(job: :organization)` ensures you have inner joins between `job_postings`, `jobs` and `organizations` tables correctly. Try executing this in the `rails console` with `.to_sql` to check the generated query if you want to explore how Rails performs joins.

Comment: if I make the query: "JobPosting.joins(job: :organization).where(organizations: { department: 'conferences' })" then I get an error: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "conferences", where I am using ActiveRecord:Enum for the department attribute and :conferences is an option, see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081716/activerecordenum-pginvalidtextrepresentation-error-invalid-input-syntax

Comment: Thanks for this answer though, it answered my question, it just created another question.