# ActiveRecord::Enum - PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, enums

I am having a strange error and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I have a model called Organizations, and a attribute called `department`, see the excerpt from the schema below:

```
t.integer  "department",  default: 0
```

Inside my model have defined my enums for this attribute, as I am using [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), like below:

```
enum department: [:conferences, :design_teams, :services, :clubs, :events, :communications]
```

But when I query, `JobPosting.joins(job: :organization).where(organizations: { department: 'conferences' })` I get an error that reads:

`PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "conferences"`

FYI: An Organization has_many Jobs, and Job has_many JobPostings.

But when I query `Organization.where(department: 'conferences')` it works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on ror5.

```
JobPosting.joins(job: :organization).where(organizations: 
{ department: Organization.departments['conferences'] })
```

I'm not even sure if `enum` was [available](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Enum/enum) in ror3.

Comment: In RoR 3 enum was not available.

Answer (score 1):

Other way is to set text-based enums. In my opinion it is the best way for enum:

```
DEPARTMENTS_ENUM = [:conferences, :design_teams, :services, :clubs, :events, :communications]
enum department: Hash[*DEPARTMENTS_ENUM.collect{|v| [v, v]}.flatten()]
```

It will work after department column type will change.

```
Organization.where(department: 'conferences')
```

Will work too

Answer (score 0):

I am not directly answering the question but as it is the first link on google when  we search `PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input value for enum`

it can help:

it is possible to declare our enum like this, this way it will not convert the string to an integer but let this job to postgresql.

`enum provider: { ig: "ig", fb: "fb", powertrack: "powertrack", gnip: "gnip" }`